# Laravel 5 | Overwrites record with previous record | Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my code,
I try to add more than one record at a time with "php artisan tinker".

MY INPUT:

```
  $tag = new App\tags
     => App\tags {#666}
  $tag->name = 'General'
     => "General"
  $tag->save()
     => true
```

Then i get as,

```
  App\tags::get()
  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#696
 all: [
   App\tags {#702
     id: "7",
     name: "General",
     created_at: "2016-02-11 05:18:33",
     updated_at: "2016-02-11 05:18:33",
   },
 ],
 }
```

After i add another one,

```
$tag->name = 'Private'
=> "Private"
$tag->save()
=> true
```

Then i get again,

```
App\tags::get()
   => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#694
 all: [
   App\tags {#692
     id: "7",
     name: "Private",
     created_at: "2016-02-11 10:48:59",
     updated_at: "2016-02-11 05:18:59",
   },
 ],
}
```

Also i try "::all()", i get the same result.

Whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Its just overwrites the previous one and update the current record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't creating a new tag before you set `$tag->name = 'Private'`

run `$tag = new App\tags` again first.

Comment: But, why i cant continuously add records.

Comment: You can, you just need to make a new tag first.  `$tag` is still holding the first tag, so you are just changing its name.

Comment: You can continuously add records, but the record is tied to that object. So when you update the object you update the row in the database. You must create a new object to represent a new row in the database. You might try `App\Tags::create(['name' => 'Private'])` which will execute the save for you and always create a new record.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan no problem! Please accept the answer if it helped you :)